# How to load multiple unpacked extensions into Chrome using Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I try to load 2 UNPACKED chrome extensions using Selenium and python

I am stuck because below code adds only the last extension so one extension is added instead of two. SO this line is executed only:

```
options.add_argument("load-extension=/Users/path/Downloads/python/proj/folder/ext_2_folder")
```

What can be a reason of that?

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()


options.add_argument("load-extension=/Users/path/Downloads/python/proj/folder/ext_1_folder")
options.add_argument("load-extension=/Users/path/Downloads/python/proj/folder/ext_2_folder")
s = Service('/Users/path/Downloads/python/proj/folder/chromedriver')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)
driver.get("chrome://extensions")
```

Answer (score 0):

You should just provide comma separated paths...

```
chrome_options = Options()

unpacked_extension_a = ".../a"
unpacked_extension_b = ".../b"

chrome_options.add_argument("load-extension=" + unpacked_extension_a +','+ unpacked_extension_b)
```